AJAX GET-request mishandles certain combination of letters
I have spent hours on finding out why a SQL query of mine, sent from Javascript to PHP via a AJAX GET-request, works in most, but not all, cases. Search terms like "Ceva" or "1111" erroneously led to empty results. Meanwhile I have found out that the search parameter added to the GET-request gets distorted on arrival in the PHP procedure: "Ceva" turns to "�va", and "1111" becomes "�11". What can I do here?
The distortion clearly takes place before the SQL query in the PHP procedure: Javascript sends the request by
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/folder/procedure.php?sql='+sql,true);
xhr.send();

and, immediately after arrival in the PHP procedure,
echo $_GET["sql"];

shows the funny phenomena described above.
I was contemplating using a Javascript equivalent of the PHP method mysqli_real_escape_string, but I am not aware of any.
Any help is appreciated.

For starters, you should apply proper URL encoding to values you are inserting into the query string. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Could I send any SQL query to your database? Isn't that a security problem?

Thank you, @CBroe, that helped! I wrapped the search term in encodeURIComponent, i.e. sql = encodeURIComponent(sql), on the Javascript side, and the problem is solved!
Thanks a lot.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
